# How to allow mousemove on image and prevent image dragging

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I've got a very simple image resizing script.  What I am trying to figure out is how to prevent the ghost image dragging while still allowing the user to drag the cursor on mousedown /mousemove and resize the image.  Here is what I have so far, and is this possible?  Currently I have it set on double click to allow the resizing with mousemove but I would like to get it set up where on mousedown allow mousemove to resize the image, and then on mouseup, cancel the resizing.

Thanks in advance.

Code:

```
$(".grid_content > img").live('mousedown',function(e){
    $(this).attr('id','image');
    $(this).css('cursor','se-resize');
    var positionX;
    var startWidth;
    var image = document.getElementById('image');
    if(!e){e = window.event};
    positionX = (e.clientX);
    startWidth = image.width;
    image.onmousemove = function(e) {
        if(!e){e = window.event};
        image.style.width = (startWidth + (e.clientX - positionX)) + 'px';
    };
    image.onmousedown = function() {
        image.onmousemove = null;
        positionX = null;
        startWidth = null;
    };
});
```

Tried this but no luck, disables the whole dragging thing:

```
$('.grid_content > img').bind("dragstart",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Have you thought of using jquery's resize element and hook on the stop event?

Comment: I have not, do you have a good example?  And I would prefer to not use jquery's UI for resizing.  I hate all the extra divs.

Comment: Do you have a fiddle for this?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/yZuhn/ Here is the link to my current working example.  See question about for modifying to mousedown drag without ghost image

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8712303/use-dragstart-preventdefault-to-disable-browser-default-image-drag-but-it-disa)

Comment: Possibly, but not quite sure on the same page.